# Rerender React component from legacy (plain JS) app

Tags: reactjs

In a legacy web application, we try to introduce React step by step. Our first component is a date picker that simply has one props with the initial value:

`<DatePicker date="2020-08-15" />`

This works fine in basic cases.

Now we want to use the component on an event list page where multiple events are listed. If the user clicks on an event then a small editor dialog will be shown where the event date can be edited. The event date is in a data attribute like this:

```
<div class="event" data-event-date="2020-08-15">...</div>
<div class="event" data-event-date="2020-09-25">...</div>
<div class="event" data-event-date="2020-10-07">...</div>
```

Please note that this page uses plain JavaScript, so a simple click event handler is assigned to all event items. This event handler shows the dialog with the DatePicker React component.

How can I rerender the DatePicker component with the date value assigned to the selected event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a very quick mockup. You would need to implement more robust checks and obviously adapt the specifics to your codebase, but this illustrates basic vanilla/React interaction.

```js
let DATE = null;

function Confirmation({date}) {
  return (
        <div>
      {date ? (
            <DatePicker date={date} />
        ) : null
        }
    </div>
  );
}

function DatePicker({date}) {
    return (
    <div class="datepicker">{date}</div>
  );
}

function setDate(e) {
    DATE = e ? e.target.getAttribute('data-event-date') : null;
  ReactDOM.render(<Confirmation date={DATE} />, document.getElementById("root"));
}

document.querySelectorAll('.event').forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click',(e) => setDate(e)))

ReactDOM.render(<Confirmation data={DATE} />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
#container {
  margin: 8px auto;
}

btn {
  background-color: gray;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 4px;
  margin: 8px;
}

.datepicker {
  padding: 8px;
  margin: 8px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <btn type="button" class="event" data-event-date="2020-08-15">2020-08-15</btn>
  <btn type="button" class="event" data-event-date="2020-09-25">2020-09-25</btn>
  <btn type="button" class="event" data-event-date="2020-10-07">2020-10-07</btn>
  <btn type="button" class="event" onClick="setDate(null)">Clear</btn>

  <div id="root"></div>
</div>
```